# How to convert a byte array to an image and open it with some process without creating a file on the disk?

Tags: c#

How to convert `Byte array` to an `image` and open with some process (such as Windows Photo Viewer)?

In here i don't want to convert array data to an image file and save it in the disk, what i would like to do is to convert byte array to a memory stream or such a thing and using this i want to open that specific image.

Is it possible? (not to show them in a picture box or such a thing).

Comment: Since you are not wanting to open it up in a picture box, what are you wanting to show it in. an external app ?

Comment: A lot will depend on whether the external app you want to use will except a memorystream and/or a bitmap object as an argument.  Start with an app that will do what you want and work back wards from there.

Comment: I do believe this can be done via memory mapped files, but I haven't ever worked with them.

Comment: @Mark Hall yes I want to show them in a external application

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to open it in an external viewer unless it's a file.  However, if you don't care about that file, use a temporary one:

```
public void ViewImage(Byte[] ImageBytes)
{
    try
    {
        Byte[] ba = new Byte[1];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ba))
        {
            Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
            String tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
            tmpFile = Path.ChangeExtension(tmpFile, "jpg");
            img.Save(tmpFile);
            if (File.Exists(tmpFile))
                Process.Start(tmpFile);  //Windows will use file association to open a viewer
        }
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryException ex)
    {
        //React appropriately
    }
}
```

Since this forces saving the image as a JPG, if the type of the original image is important, more logic should be added to deal with that fact.